# Weblogic Server Cluster Setup 11g - Setting up a Server Instance and Cluster

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, weblogic, weblogic11g

I'm looking to set up a Clustered Server up on Web Logic.  I walk though the following steps and yet when I restart my server then start the cluster I get an exception.  The exception is listed below.

Here are the steps I go through on the Console in Web Logic

```
Create Cluster

In the console page mydomain.com/7002/console on the left side 
I click on

    Environment 

to expand the tree and then click on 

Clusters

It changes screens on the right.  I fill out the data for the 

CLUSTER NAME

and I left the messaging mode to Uni-Cast

The multicast address and port are already filled out but are greyed out.

I then click OK.

After this I configure the server.  On the side on the console page I click on Servers

Server Config


I fill out the Server Name: MyServer

I punch in the Server Listen Address

Port is defaulted to 7001 which is available

I then fill out the question

Should this server belong to a cluster

I answer

Yes, Make this a server a member of an existing cluster and I select the cluster I just created.

I then click Finish
```

After I accept the changes and reboot the server, when I start up the instance of the server I get the below exception in the error logs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
####<Sep 20, 2016 1:57:25 PM CDT> <Debug> <ServerLifeCycle> <DIFDX> <WLS_RUN_MANAGER> <main> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1474397845602> <BEA-000000> <calling halt on weblogic.nodemanager.NMService@3c3d22af> 
####<Sep 20, 2016 1:57:25 PM CDT> <Debug> <DiagnosticContext> <> <> <weblogic.timers.TimerThread> <> <> <> <1474397845604> <BEA-000000> <Invoked DCM.initialValue() for thread id=15, name=weblogic.timers.TimerThread
java.lang.Exception
    at weblogic.diagnostics.context.DiagnosticContextManager$1.initialValue(DiagnosticContextManager.java:267)
    at weblogic.kernel.ResettableThreadLocal.initialValue(ResettableThreadLocal.java:117)
    at weblogic.kernel.ResettableThreadLocal$ThreadStorage.get(ResettableThreadLocal.java:204)
    at weblogic.kernel.ResettableThreadLocal.get(ResettableThreadLocal.java:74)
    at weblogic.diagnostics.context.DiagnosticContextManager$WLSDiagnosticContextFactoryImpl.findOrCreateDiagnosticContext(DiagnosticContextManager.java:365)
    at weblogic.diagnostics.context.DiagnosticContextFactory.findOrCreateDiagnosticContext(DiagnosticContextFactory.java:111)
    at weblogic.diagnostics.context.DiagnosticContextFactory.findOrCreateDiagnosticContext(DiagnosticContextFactory.java:94)
    at weblogic.diagnostics.context.DiagnosticContextHelper.getContextId(DiagnosticContextHelper.java:32)
    at weblogic.logging.LogEntryInitializer.getCurrentDiagnosticContextId(LogEntryInitializer.java:117)
    at weblogic.logging.LogEntryInitializer.initializeLogEntry(LogEntryInitializer.java:67)
    at weblogic.logging.WLLogRecord.<init>(WLLogRecord.java:43)
    at weblogic.logging.WLLogRecord.<init>(WLLogRecord.java:54)
    at weblogic.logging.WLLogger.normalizeLogRecord(WLLogger.java:64)
    at weblogic.logging.WLLogger.log(WLLogger.java:35)
    at weblogic.diagnostics.debug.DebugLogger.log(DebugLogger.java:231)
    at weblogic.diagnostics.debug.DebugLogger.debug(DebugLogger.java:204)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningDebugLogger.debug(SelfTuningDebugLogger.java:18)
    at weblogic.work.ServerWorkManagerImpl$1.log(ServerWorkManagerImpl.java:44)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.debug(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:597)
    at weblogic.work.RequestManager.log(RequestManager.java:1204)
    at weblogic.work.RequestManager.addToCalendarQueue(RequestManager.java:315)
    at weblogic.work.RequestManager.addToPriorityQueue(RequestManager.java:301)
    at weblogic.work.RequestManager.executeIt(RequestManager.java:248)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.scheduleInternal(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:164)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.schedule(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:144)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerManagerFactoryImpl$WorkManagerExecutor.execute(TimerManagerFactoryImpl.java:132)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerManagerImpl.waitForStop(TimerManagerImpl.java:241)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerManagerImpl.stop(TimerManagerImpl.java:98)
    at weblogic.timers.internal.TimerThread$Thread.run(TimerThread.java:250)
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no clash between your admin server instance's IP/port and MyServer's IP/port?

Comment: Found my solution.  It ended up being a timeout issue.  The server was taking such a long time to come up that the instance was assuming no response back and thus assuming it couldn't get though.  Once I increased the timeout to be longer, it finally came through and worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: It ended up being a timeout issue.  The server was taking such a long time to come up that the instance was assuming no response back and thus assuming it couldn't get though.  Once I increased the timeout to be longer, it finally came through and worked.